# What is the correct way to save data that will be sent from server to client via socket after client reestablish its lost connection

Tags: android, asp.net-core, signalr

I have `.net core` written `api` and `android mobile` client. There is `signalr` socket connection between two of them. When user opens an `event` on mobile app, i save this `event data` to `db` on server and send it to other `users` that listens the `event creator` via socket. 
 
I periodically control the socket connection on mobile app and i can reconnect them if they have lost their connection. I have no problem so far.. But i have problem keeping the `data` for `lost connection user`

***Let me explain with example :***

 
**There are Users : `Producer1`, `Consumer1`, `Consumer2`**

 
If `Producer1` opens an event via `mobile app`. It sends `data` to the `server` via `httprequest` and i save it to `db`.

 
After saving the data to `db`, i send this `data` to `Consumer1` and `Consumer2` via `socket connection`. 
Lets say `Consumer2` dont have network connection while sending the `event data`.

 
`Consumer1` that have network connection, gets the `data` successfully and i have no problem for `Consumer1`.

But, `Consumer2` couldn't get the `data` because it lost their socket connection and we did not reconnect yet.
The sent `event data` already gone. So `Consumer2` will not get the `event data`.

My question is, how can i keep the `data` and send it for `Consumer2` when just `Consumer2` reestablish its connection. What is the efficient and correct way to doing this.

**Server Side Code Example :**

```
    public async Task AddEvent(GetEventOutput getEventOutput)
    {
        if(getEventOutput.Active)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(SignalR_EVENT + QUESTION_MARK + EVENT_WITH_USER + EQUAL_DASH + getEventOutput.UserID).SendAsync(CREATE_EVENT_ON_MOBILE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getEventOutput));
            sendEventCreateNotification(getEventOutput);
        }
    }
```

**Client Side Code Example :**

```
    hubConnection.on(CREATE_EVENT_ON_MOBILE, (getEventOutput) -> {
        System.out.println("CREATE_EVENT_ON_MOBILE : ");
        setUiAfterSignalrHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isNullOrEmpty(getEventOutput)) {
                    Event event = gson.fromJson(getEventOutput, Event.class);
                    eventsWithTimerRecyclerViewAdapter.insertItem(0, event);
                    setUiAfterSignalrHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    leftAndRightTextWithTimerRecyclerView.removeEmptyPlaceHolder(eventsWithTimerRecyclerViewAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
        restartSocket();
    }, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

We had similar situation but with notifications. To avoid your problem, I would recommend to use cache or volatile storage to store those events.

For example, when you send your event to the clients, they should invoke a callback method registering that they received the event, then you register your event as completed when all the subscribers responded the event successfully and you can dispose the event.

But the perform this you should have:

- List of all connected clients that wants to receive the event.
- Storage for those events (we use Cosmos Db but cache will work well).

So you will not dispose the event until it is completed. But then how you resend the event to the user that was not connected on that time?

Just create a hub method to be invoked by the client just after the connection is establish to send pending events (events that this user has not registered as received, so they did not invoked the callback method).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So trick is the volatile for me. 
Actually I have some methods waiting to be validate before use. 
So your method is already in my "possibilities list", 
i'm searchin for keywords to reach most efficient way to create my structure and you validate one of them. It was a very clear and descriptive answer. Thank you again.